# MDX: Set Alias for a Column

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, cube

I'm ok with T-SQL but very much a newbie to MDX. I have the query below which outputs something like

```
Age European | ParameterCaption | ParameterValue | ParameterLevel
-----------------------------------------------------------------
XXX          | XXX              | XXX            | XXX
```

However, I would like `Age European` to read as something I designate e.g. `The Age`. Any ideas? Code below:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS
  IIf (
      ( [Age At Activity].[Age European].CurrentMember .Member_Caption ) = "1 - 4", "01 - 04",
  IIf ([Age At Activity].[Age European].CurrentMember .Member_Caption = "5 - 9", "05 - 09", [Age At Activity].[Age European].CurrentMember .Member_Caption )
      )
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS
  [Age At Activity].[Age European].CurrentMember.UniqueName
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS
  [Age At Activity].[Age European].CurrentMember .Level .Ordinal
SELECT
{ [Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel] } ON COLUMNS,
Order ( [Age At Activity].[Age European].[Age European].Members, [Measures].[ParameterCaption], BASC ) ON ROWS
FROM ReportingPBR
```

Comment: you already have `ParameterValue` ? why not rename that meaure as "The Age"

Comment: Try changing the name of column in SSRS itself.

Comment: @SouravA I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: @whytheq -  these kind of measures get created in SSRS when a user doesn't declare them on top. SSRS creates these "hidden measures" to accommodate for the parameters. (http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/tag/hidden-datasets/). OP want to change the name of one of the fields in the output. Instead of touching the MDX, the column can be renamed at the reporting end; that's my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this column:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[The Age] AS
  [Age At Activity].[Age European].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
```